# Azure Mobile App Workflow

Tags: c#, android, sql-server, azure, uwp

After using *Azure Mobile Services* a year ago, I decided to get back to mobile development but *Microsoft* changed a lot in their offer and I'm actually struggling to set my project up.

My goal is to create a service whith these features:

- *.NET* backend preferred over the *Javascript* one (I don't like callbacks :))
- SSO (*Facebook*, *Twitter*, *Google+*, *Windows Live*)
- SQL Database (I really **need** relations, and I already have a *T-SQL* schema)
- Push Notifications (just to *Windows* and *Android* for now and with unlimited custom channels so that I can have one channel for each user and avoid dealing with notifications' logic)
- Monthly scheduled jobs to update database from an external *JSON API* and to remove old entries
- Mobile Client (with a shared Xamarin library to handle all the data-related stuff and *WUP* + *Android* support)
- Web Client (I don't have a *Mac* so I can't build and publish the *iOS* version, so a web app may be needed as a temporary replacement)

What I did was to:

- Open *Azure Preview Portal* [link](https://portal.azure.com)
- Click on *New* => *Web + Mobile* => *Mobile App*
- Set the *Resource Group* with all the needed plans
- Added a *Data Connection* to a newly created *SQL Database*
- Added a *Notification Hub* with settings for *GCM* and *WNS*
- Added *Mobile Authentication* with settings for *Microsoft Account*, *Facebook*, *Twitter*, *Google*
- Created the *schema* for my *SQL Database*

Before going on, I'm not sure that this was the correct workflow but documentation is pretty confused and the *Get Started* sections just discuss about code and not how to properly setup the service and have it running, so I just did the same basic things that I would've done with the old *Mobile Service*, plus dealing with the *SQL Database* instead of the *NOSQL* one.

Now it comes the issue: I have no idea on how to move next, and even the *Quickstart* projects (both server and client) are not helpful (they're the old *TodoItem* sample working with the *Mobile Service*).

The first thing that I wanted to do was to create the *Scheduled Job* because I actually need to fill the database with the external data before moving forward. 
The only thing close to what I need is the *WebJob*, but I can't schedule it yet and it requires me to upload an *exe* file while I'd like to be able to write my *C#* code directly to the server (being able to remotely debug it).
An alternative may be to create a *Compute Instace* and write an endless loop doing what I need, but this will force me to manually deal with the *SQL Database* inside the *Mobile App Service*.

Another issue is related to the *SQL Database*. As I already wrote, the *Quickstart* seems to work with the *NOSQL* included in the old *Mobile Service*, meaning that I don't have a direct connection to my *SQL Database*, while I'd like to be able something like

`App.MobileService.GetTable<MyTable>()`

Plus, having 10 tables, I'd also like to have a way to map them automatically (like *NetBeans* does for *JavaEE* projects).

So the question is: what's *a good* (or the best) workflow to get everything working as I need it or, at least, close to how I need it?
(I know that answers may be opionion-based but they still may be useful since *Microsoft*'s documentation is not complete)

Comment: Have you seen this article? I realize the documentation for Mobile Apps is not as complete, but it does cover the basics.  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-xamarin-ios-get-started-preview/

Comment: This is the first thing I saw, but it works only if you have the classical `TodoItem` table, while it doesn't say how to work with a different schema, so how to create entities from database, controllers and stuff like that. Plus, my app doesn't even show up in the wizard, I can oly publish by downloading the profile.

Comment: Hey @StepTNT, we have actually been talking about publishing versions of the quickstart project that are already enabled for both authentication and push notifications. I think this would help for cases like yours where you want all the goodies (auth, push, data) and have already completed the backend configuration at one time, rather than having to go through each tutorial in sequence (quickstart, then auth, then push). Would it have been helpful for you to be able to download a project like that, and simply swap out the Mobile Apps connection values?

Comment: Absolutely yes. Any ETA on this? Also having the tutorials updated for the new App Service would be a great idea, since something still refers to the old Mobile Service causing confusion.

Comment: import webbrowser
while True: webbrowser.open("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33037315/azure-mobile-app-workflow", new = 9)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an existing database, you could use [Entity Framework Code First to Existing Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx). That will generate the C# classes for you.

The database that you create when you add a Data Connection to your Mobile App is an Azure SQL Database by default--I'm not sure why you thought it was NoSQL?

Once you have done this, you can query your tables from the Azure Mobile Apps client SDK. For instance, in Xamarin, the quickstart project does queries as follows (see https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services-quickstarts/blob/MobileApp/client/xamarin.android/ZUMOAPPNAME/ToDoActivity.cs#L126).

`var list = await toDoTable.Where (item => item.Complete == false).ToListAsync ();`

Finally, regarding your question on WebJobs, you can actually schedule it. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/#CreateScheduledCRON for more information. Even though you Web Deploy your webjob target, you can still remote debug it. See this blog post for information: http://www.bursteg.com/remote-debugging-azure-webjobs-attach-a-debugger-from-server-explorer/